# asyncio.gather doesn't execute my task in same time

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I am using asyncio.gather to run many query to an API. My main goal is to execute them all without waiting one finish for start another one.

```
async def main():    
    order_book_coroutines = [asyncio.ensure_future(get_order_book_list()) for exchange in exchange_list]
    results = await asyncio.gather(*order_book_coroutines)



async def get_order_book_list():
    print('***1***')
    sleep(10)
    try:
       #doing API query
    except Exception as e:
        pass
    print('***2***')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

My main problem here is the ouput :

```
***1***
***2***
***1***
***2***
***1***
***2***
```

I was waiting something like :

```
***1***
***1***
***1***
***2***
***2***
***2***
```

There is a problem with my code ? or i miss understood asyncio.gather utility ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a problem with my code? Or I misunderstood the `asyncio.gather` utility?

No, you did not. The expected output would be shown if you used `await asyncio.sleep(10)` instead of `time.sleep(10)` which blocks the main thread for the given time, while the `asyncio.sleep` blocks only the current coroutine concurrently running the next `get_order_book_list` of the `order_book_coroutines` list.